# Apache mod_jk serves JSP through HTTP but fails to server JSP via HTTPS protocol?

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, mod-jk

I am running a application on JBoss4.0.3(using Tomcat AJP on ports 8009 and 8443) and I just setup a Apache HTTPS server that is listening on both port 443 and port 80.   Everything works fine via port 80:  Apache seems to process JSP pages handled by Tomcat via the AJP connection.   On the other hand, if I access my server on the HTTPS (443) protocol, the Apache will only serve its own static content and does not know about the JSP application.  It is as-if AJP doesn't work when Apache is serving via port 443.

Can anyone offer any advice on this?

Here are my SSL options in the httpd-ssl.conf file:

```
SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth +ExportCertData +StrictRequire +StdEnvVars
```

Also, after enabling mod_proxy and mod_proxy_ajp, putting this in my httpd-ssl.conf will causes my server not to be able to start:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
.......
<Location>
    ProxyPass ajp://localhost:8009/
</Location>
.......
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AJP isn't an encrypted protocol; there's no reason to use more than just the 8009 listener.  (your `+ExportCertData` will feed tomcat the certificate info when it's an SSL session)

We need to see your full to be able to tell you why it's not working, not just the SSLOptions; anything useful in apache's `error.log` (probably under `/var/log/apache2`) would be good as well.  As to the snippet that causes the server not to start, try this:

```
<Location />
    ProxyPass ajp://localhost:8009/
    ProxyPassReverse ajp://localhost:8009/
</Location>
```

Comment: Great, that worked but , strangely, it killed my "RedirectMatch" rules that I configured to redirect some URLs to a proper URI .  How do I get my Redirects to work again?  Maybe I need to switch to a mod_rewrite rule or something?

Comment: Works only without the "/" in your ProxyPass directive.  Edit it and fix it and ill give the points.

Comment: Yes, my mistake; when inside a `<Location>` block the first argument is implied.